# Максимальное из средних значений

Tags: sql-server, sql

Как получить максимальное из средних значений, не используя при этом: подзапросы, дополнительные таблицы, курсоры, предложение GROUP BY ?

Comment: что вы подразумеваете под "средних значений" ?

Comment: среднее арифметическое

Answer (score 1):

Вообще - никак! Как-бы не извращаться - всё равно будет group by ( явно или не явно ).

Можно так:

```
select
  avg_mark
from
  (
    select
      avg_mark,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY avg_mark DESC ) as rnk
    from
      (
        select distinct
          AVG( Mark ) OVER( PARTITION BY Student_ID ) as avg_mark
        from
          StudentMarks
      ) t
  ) t
where
  rnk = 1
```

UPD:

```
select top 1
  AVG( Mark )
from
  StudentMarks
group by
  Student_ID
order by
  AVG( Mark ) Desc
```

Comment: Понял БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Можно ли зделать все тоже через оконные функции и функции ранжирования без подзапросов???

Comment: Тут нет подзапросов! Данные планомерно изменяются....

Хм... Подумал... Конкретно этот запрос - можно переделать... Обновил ответ

Comment: timka_s ваш запрос работает правельно но не доконца!

1) Если поле Mark привести например к типу float то может быть такоая ситуация когда студентов с одинковым максимальным средним балом может быть несколько а ваш запрос вернет только одного студента;

2) Необходимо привязывать максимальный средний бал к имени студента, как в примере мною ранее приведенном, что у вас отсутствует.

Comment: @reactor, Причём тут студент?) Тут получения максимума среднего, ни о каких студентах речи небыло... И скорее всего проще ( по стоимости ) сначала получить эту величину, а потом уже студентов...

Answer (score 0):

среднее вряд ли получится получить без group by или вы что-то не дорассказываете про данные. Если набор средних получите - отсортируйте их и выведите максимум с помощью TOP 1

Comment: Пример. Есть две таблицы:
--1)
create table Students(
 ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
 StudentName varchar(200) not null);
--2)
create table StudentMarks(
 ID int identity (1,1) primary key not null,
 Student_ID int not null references Students (ID),
 Mark int not null check (mark between 1 and 5));
Отобразить список студентов, которые имеют максимальный средний балл. 
Если испол. предложение group by то я решил в SQL SERVER 2008 след. обр:
SELECT TOP 1 WIHT TIES avg(Mark), StudentName  AS avg_mark FROM Students st INNER JOIN StudentMarks stm ON st.ID = stm.ID
GROUP BY avg_mark;

Comment: @reactor, ниужели ваш запрос работает?? в нём как минимум 2 ошибки - группировка по несуществующему полю, и неверное соединение

Comment: Исправляю!
SELECT TOP 1 WIHT TIES StudentName, avg(Mark) avg_mark
FROM Students st JOIN StudentMarks stm ON st.ID = stm.ID 
GROUP BY StudentName
ORDER BY avg_mark DESC;

Comment: @reactor, Что вы исправили-то?)

Поля avg_mark - не существует, и делать по нему группировку - нельзя...

st.ID = stm.Student_ID - таблицы должны соединяться по этим полям!!

Comment: Уважаемый timka_s на счет st.ID = stm.Student_ID вы совершенно правы, но по поводу ORDER BY avg_mark DESC я с вами не согласен в силу того, что в операторе SELECT выполняеться до ORDER BY по факту, чего нелязя сказать судя по порядку следования ключевых слов в предложении(см.http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)

Answer (score 0):

я бы поговнокодил %)

```
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl`"),0);
$sum = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(field) FROM `tbl`"),0);
$mean = round($sum/$count);
```

Comment: Прикол в том, что данную задачу нужно решить в SQL SERVER 2008 и только!!!

Comment: @reactor, к сожалению (или может к счастью) не пользовался sql server'ом, не знаю что там да как.

там разве нету подобного функционала?

Comment: я не вкурсе)))